# Heroku Deployment - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/passwd-'

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Can anyone help me with this error? I don't what's wrong with the code. is it a database credentials error? Is it an application code error? Is it a Linux/Unix related error?

This is my first time to deploy my application on Heroku but I got this error message:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/passwd-'

```
   python ph_dorms/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "ph_dorms/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
       collected = self.collect()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
       handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 353, in copy_file
       with source_storage.open(path) as source_file:
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 33, in open
       return self._open(name, mode)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 218, in _open
       return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/passwd-'
   !     Error while running '$ python ph_dorms/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
   See traceback above for details.
   You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
   Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
      $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
  !     Push failed
```

Comment: @Norrius: I am trying to deploy my application from a github repo but I am getting this error. Is there a config I need to look at here? This is my first time to use heroku so not sure where to go for this error.

Comment: Sorry, feel free to disregard my previous comment. `/etc/passwd-` is a backup of `/etc/passwd`, the file that stores system user's credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complicated part in deploying a django webapp is most of the time related to the collectstatics only if you didn't setup everything correctly to serve static files from the same server.

First disable the collectstatics running the following in your terminal or cmd:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Then deploy again.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable collectstatic on heroku and use whitenoise to serve staticfiles in production.

Run in your cmd (with heroku cli installed)

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 1
```

Or add DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC with value equal to 1 to your environment variables in heroku.

Then, use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve static files in production.